# Как вывести картинку в консоль браузера?

Tags: javascript

Я искал в интернете способ вывода картинки в консоль
Нашёл это

`console.log('%c ', 'font-size:400px; background:url(https://pics.me.me/codeit-google-until-youfinda-stackoverflow-answerwith-code-to-copy-paste-34126823.png) no-repeat;');`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885562/google-chrome-console-print-image

Но он не работает.Есть ли рабочие методы вывода в браузерную консоль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что Chrome удалил поддержку фоновых изображений в консоли в Chrome 101 и Edge 101 (во всяком случае по прямой ссылке)

Но все еще работает в Safari 15.4.

Однако если вместо прямой ссылки сделать base64 картинку, то всё получится. Т.е.

```
console.log('%c ', "font-size:400px; background:url('data:image/jpeg;base64,ТУТ КОД') no-repeat;");
```

Должен работать...**пока что**

Пример привести не могу, т.к. base64 строка не вместится в ответ ruSO по длине символов